# How to simulate an incoming tcp packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, simulation

I've created a simple application that listens to certain incoming TCP messages

I could write a bit of code to send out a TCP message manually, but I was wondering if there was an easier way of sending "fake" incoming TCP messages. I searched around a bit but I didn't find an easy method of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by "_send_ an _incoming_ message"?  Incoming messages are received.

Answer (score 1):

If your application has a simple text protocol, you can just use `telnet localhost port`. Otherwise look into `netcat`